# How to check if a path is a relative symlink in python?

Tags: python

`os` package has
`os.path.islink(path)`
to check if `path` is a symlink.
How do I determine if a file located at `path` is a *relative* symlink?

Note that `path` can be an absolute path (i.e. `path == os.path.abspath(path)`), e.g. `/home/user/symlink` that is a relative symlink to `../` which is relative. As opposed to a link to `/home/user`, which points to the same directory but is absolute.

Comment: No a totally reliable test, but you can check if the absolute path is the same as the same as the link as you said, with some level of canonizalization in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to read the actual target pathname and check it.

```
def isrellink(path):
    return os.path.islink(path) and not os.path.isabs(os.readlink(path))
```